# Integrate Office 365 Excel Online in Web Application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, office365

Given Excel online is an excellent spread sheet implementation for the web, it would be desirable to use it as a spread sheet component in web applications.

We are using an angularjs frontend and an ASP.NET backend and would like to use Excel online essentially as a spread sheet component inlined into the web app.

Browsing the web, I don't see any suggestion on how to integrate Excel online into my own web application. Has anyone managed to do it?

Answer (score 5):

We can use WOPI protocol to integrate with Office Online in our web application. Here are two figures show you how it works:

[image]

[image]

And you can get a sample code to implement the WOPI server from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Building-an-Office-Web-f98650d6#content). And below are some helpful links for you get started:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officedevdocs/2013/03/21/introducing-wopi/

https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. From what I read, this requires always an underlying document. Do you know if it is possible just to display and edit ad-hoc content? As mentioned above, we'd like to use it essentially as a normal html5 control and not necessarily to edit .xlsx files.

Comment: It seems that you want to only integrate with Office online view feature, if I understood correctly we can use “View Office documents online” feature to create an link for view the document which store on your web site. More detail please refer to [here](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-online/view-office-documents-online)

Comment: Actually, I just wanted to use the spread sheet control without underlying .xlsx file, but I doubt that it is possible. Nevertheless, thanks for your suggestions, I will try them out anyway.