# Edit and modify Word and Excel files from within the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, office365

I have a Ruby on Rails application where users can upload files. We run this application in production on home-rolled linux servers. (No Heroku or anything like that.) Using the carrierwave gem, they get stored on AWS S3. Very simple and straight-forward.

If someone wanted to view or modify those files that are stored on S3 without having to download them, open them in Word or Excel, and then reupload- how could that be done?

The only people who have seemed to implement something like this are Dropbox and Citrix ShareFile. They did it using Office Online.

I don't mind moving file storage off S3 to somewhere else (or even something home-rolled) to implement this feature- but it needs to be as reliable and robust as S3.

We've tried to something with WebDAV, but it is fragile and seems to be deprecated.

We would consider any solution, paid or free.

Comment: hmm if Dropbox uses Office Online, then I think Office Online has some way of embeding, like how youtube can be embedded

Comment: Are you sure Dropbox allows you to modify Office files online? As far as I know, they just convert the files to PDF, then show them using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).

Comment: We can use WOPI to  integrate with Office Online in our web application. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321497/integrate-office-365-excel-online-in-web-application/37343605#37343605) to see whether it is helpful.

Comment: Wander Nauta- no, you can, but you need and Office 365 liscens.
https://blogs.dropbox.com/dropbox/2015/04/dropbox-and-office-online

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use the WOPI framework for this. There are quite a lot of resources and code samples for this, of which the most useful might be [This Github Repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-WOPI). The framework allows you to programmatically integrate into the Word Online viewer/editor.

Hope this helps,
Jesse